# GetStatusHistoryForPastWeek modification

Tags: javascript, thingworx

I am trying to modify the Asset Monitor Performance Controller's service "GetStatusHistoryForPastWeek"
To do the same thing for 1 day. But I just can't get into the code. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to seek help on their forum: https://community.ptc.com/

Comment: I never used Asset Monitor Performance, but If GetStatusHistoryForPastWeek it's Java based (not Javascript) you won't be able to modify it, that's the reason you can't see the code on ThingWorx. In order to modify a ThingWorx Java extension you need the Java extension source code, and rebuild it (all of it).